# Why does the hover animation ignore the transition time and function in Gtk3?

Tags: python, css, animation, gtk, gtk3

With the new gtk, it is possible to create graphical themes with a file in something like css.

Given this css file (named `my-gtk-widgets.css`):

```
.button {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-style: solid;
}

.button:hover {
    transition: 3000ms linear;
    border-radius: 50;
}
```

And the following python code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk

def _destroy_cb(widget, data=None):
    Gtk.main_quit()

window = Gtk.Window()
window.connect("destroy", _destroy_cb)

screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()

css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
css_provider.load_from_path('my-gtk-widgets.css')

context = Gtk.StyleContext()
context.add_provider_for_screen(screen, css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)

box = Gtk.VBox()
window.add(box)

button = Gtk.Button('go-next')
box.pack_start(button, False, False, 0)

window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Running this code gives a button which changes the border-radius when hovered. But the transition is instant, not animated.

[image]

[image]

What is the reason for this? Do I need a different version of gtk, python, ... ? Or does this animation depend on the gtk theme (in my case the Ubuntu default `Ambience`)? Or is there something wrong in my css file?

python version: 2.7.2+

gtk version: 3.0

EDIT: the example is a modified version of [this](http://gnomejournal.org/article/107/styling-gtk-with-css)

Answer (score 6):

I am no expert in css, but it appears that you are trying to apply transition on a property on which transition/animation cannot be applied (From [this list](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#properties-from-css-) it appears transition on `border-radius` is not supported) You could try something like `background-color` to see the transition effects in the button in you application (Colour change transition could be seen - Gtk-3.0, python-2.7.1, FC15)

```
.button {
    background-color: #00ffff;
    border-style: solid;
}

.button:hover {
    transition: 1s linear;
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for the answer. However that does not work as well: while the background transition time changes accordingly, the background-color is not picked up (nor is e.g. border-color, padding-top, ...). So my original question remains: what do I have to change to get this to work? It seems that the css is not the main problem.

Comment: Do you mean that the background-color of the button did not change? Well I did check it before posting as I have mentioned in the response. It does change. Hmmm btw I tried it in LXDE environment & not GNOME. I don't have access to GTK+3 right now, maybe I will try to check it on GNOME

Comment: I mean that the ambiance theme does have a hover effect which changes the background color. And this change was affected by the transition time value in the css, but both color values in the css did not have any effect on the appearence of the button.

Comment: It could be because of theme as well. I am not too sure though. As you might know there is a default .css file from which theme elements could be picked if the theme has .css file. Maybe you can try with a different theme maybe Clearlooks?

Answer (score -1):

Put the transition on `.button` not `.button:hover`

Comment: this does neither work, nor would it do the same as the example *should* do, because I might want a different transition for other events.

Comment: It does influence the behaviour. The real solution is actually putting the animatable property in the css statement, like this:

`transition: border-radius 3000ms linear;`

Of course this property can vary when you have vendor prefixes.

Comment: @MatthewGreen : you **do** have seen that I asked about gtk? This has nothing to do with html, mozilla, webkit and others. It is about the gtk toolkit. The example I posted is [modified from here](http://gnomejournal.org/article/107/styling-gtk-with-css).